# Racing Doubling down

Tags: probability

You're in a race and either player can offer to double the bet at any time. We start off with a bet of $\$100$. If your opponent offers to double down during the race what must be your minimum probability of winning to accept?

The answer goes as follows;
$$200p - 100(1-p) = 0\implies p = \frac 13$$
This doesn't make sense to me as I would expect it to be $50\%$ chance. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the offer means that you either have to accept the offer or turn down the pot - that is if you decline the offer you lose your already placed bet.

Now the explanation is that if you've bet $\$100$ there's $\$200$ in the pot. The offer is to put in another \$100 for the chance of winning the pot, and your opponents additional $\$100$. That is if you win you get $\$300$ and if you lose you lose $\$100$ as the decision stands.